# Solr cannot index JSON file

Tags: json, solr, lucene

HI i am trying to index the JSON file as per

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html#indexing-json

but i get the following error in the console

```
X:\solr\solr-5.3.1\bin>java -Dc=bookcore -jar ..\example\exampledoc
s\post.jar ..\example\exampledocs\books.json
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/bookcore/update using con
tent-type application/xml...
POSTing file books.json to [base]
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: http
://localhost:8983/solr/bookcore/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">30</int
></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in p
rolog; expected '&lt;'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException
: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/bo
okcore/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/bookcore/update...
Time spent: 0:00:00.063
```

why does it say unexpected character? Shouldn't it expect a JSON file? DO i need to make some changes in the solrconfig.xml for this core? by the way, here's how i created the core

```
solr create -c bookcore
```

please help.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using post.jar directly. It is not recommended anymore, and the **post** tool is slightly smarter. The tutorial linked actually uses that approach.

So you could do

> .\post -c bookcore ..\example\exampledocs\books.json

or if you insist on using post.jar, you need to set the type as explained in other answers, but you need to make sure to pass the *-D* options before -jar command. Therefore:

> java -Dc=bookcore **-Dtype=application/json** -jar ..\example\exampledocs\post.jar ..\example\exampledocs\books.json

If you still get complaints of different kind, try quoting **"application/json"** just in case Windows is having issues with slashes.

Comment: thanks man :) that did it. i was passing the -Dtype option after the -jar. Also, i can use the post tool as i am on windows. hence i must use the post jar

Answer (score 1):

default type for POST tool is XML

-type  (default: application/xml)

Try this

```
X:\solr\solr-5.3.1\bin>java -Dc=bookcore -jar ..\example\exampledoc
s\post.jar ..\example\exampledocs\books.json -Dtype=application/json
```

Try it this way.

Comment: Try `-type application/json` instead of `-Dtype=application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

so this works

curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/bookcore/update?commit=true" --data-binary @books.json -H "Content-type:application/json"

also, windows command line does not like single quotes! i would still like to know how to get post using the JAR.